# How can I extract columns from a fixed-width format in Perl?

Tags: perl, fixed-width

I'm writing a Perl script to run through and grab various data elements such as:

```
1253592000
1253678400                 86400                 6183.000000
1253764800                 86400                 4486.000000 
1253851200  36.000000      86400                10669.000000
1253937600  0.000000       86400                 9126.000000
1254024000  0.000000       86400                 2930.000000
1254110400  0.000000       86400                 2895.000000
1254196800  0.000000                             8828.000000
```

I can grab each line of this text file no problem.

I have working regex to grab each of those fields. Once I have the line in a variable, i.e. $line - how can I grab each of those fields and place them into their own variables even though they have different delimiters?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what your delimiters are?

Comment: @Paul: That's the problem. This output is being generated by an application (splunk). I can't set the delimiters, and they seem to be just two whitespace characters between each column - but There's whitespace that extends past that.

Comment: @Greg: This really doesn't look like a "delimited" file at all.  These are fixed-width columns.  FM's solution below is really the cleanest way to parse this.

Comment: @Paul - Ok got it. Thanks. I just always refer to anything that's separated by something, delimited. But that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, that one is simple, this one implies that the fixed-width format is for a database or something more complex.

Answer (score 14):

This example illustrates how to parse the line either with whitespace as the delimiter ([split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)) or with a fixed-column layout ([unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html)). With `unpack` if you use upper-case (A10 etc), whitespace will be removed for you. **Note**: as brian d foy points out, the `split` approach does not work well for a situation with missing fields (for example, the second line of data), because the field position information will be lost; `unpack` is the way to go here, unless we are misunderstanding your data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>){
    chomp $line;
    my @fields_whitespace = split m'\s+', $line;
    my @fields_fixed = unpack('a10 a10 a12 a28', $line);
}

__DATA__
1253592000                                                  
1253678400                 86400                 6183.000000
1253764800                 86400                 4486.000000
1253851200 36.000000       86400                10669.000000
1253937600  0.000000       86400                 9126.000000
1254024000  0.000000       86400                 2930.000000
1254110400  0.000000       86400                 2895.000000
1254196800  0.000000                             8828.000000
```

Comment: Everyone forgets that Perl has pack, but it's really handy and I should use it more myself. I was just editing that chapter for the next edition of Effective Perl Programming. :)

Comment: `split m'\s+'` would highlight better.

Comment: According to the perldoc - "The string is broken into chunks described by the TEMPLATE." These chunks are inserted into the @fields_fixed array, correct?

Comment: while ($line = <TEMPFILE>)
{
        if ($x < 2) {
        $x++;
        }
        else {
        chomp $line;
        @fields_whitespace = split m'\s+', $line;
        @fields_fixed = unpack('a10 a10 a12 a28', $line);
        print @fields_fixed, "\n";
        $x++;
        }
}
That's what I have - I cannot access @fields_fixed outside the block - am I missing some basic ideal of programming that I should remember? I know and understand scope - but am confused in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Use [my module `DataExtract::FixedWidth`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DataExtract-FixedWidth/lib/DataExtract/FixedWidth.pm). It is the most full featured, and well tested, for working with Fixed Width columns in perl. If this isn't fast enough you can pass in an `unpack_string` and eliminate the need for heuristic detection of boundaries.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DataExtract::FixedWidth;
use feature ':5.10';

my @rows = <DATA>;
my $de = DataExtract::FixedWidth->new({
  heuristic => \@rows
  , header_row => undef
});

say join ('|',  @{$de->parse($_)}) for @rows;

    --alternatively if you want header info--

my @rows = <DATA>;
my $de = DataExtract::FixedWidth->new({
  heuristic => \@rows
  , header_row => undef
  , cols => [qw/timestamp field2 period field4/]
});

use Data::Dumper;
warn Dumper $de->parse_hash($_) for @rows;

__DATA__
1253592000
1253678400                 86400                 6183.000000
1253764800                 86400                 4486.000000
1253851200  36.000000      86400                10669.000000
1253937600  0.000000       86400                 9126.000000
1254024000  0.000000       86400                 2930.000000
1254110400  0.000000       86400                 2895.000000
1254196800  0.000000                             8828.000000
```

Comment: I've used this module in the past and the column detection is slick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of the column names and formatting but you should be able to adjust this recipe to your liking using [Text::FixedWidth](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-FixedWidth/)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::FixedWidth;

my $fw = Text::FixedWidth->new;
$fw->set_attributes(
    qw(
        timestamp undef  %10s
        field2    undef  %10s
        period    undef  %12s
        field4    undef  %28s
        )
);

while (<DATA>) {
    $fw->parse( string => $_ );
    print $fw->get_timestamp . "\n";
}

__DATA__
1253592000
1253678400                 86400                 6183.000000
1253764800                 86400                 4486.000000
1253851200 36.000000       86400                10669.000000
1253937600  0.000000       86400                 9126.000000
1254024000  0.000000       86400                 2930.000000
1254110400  0.000000       86400                 2895.000000
1254196800  0.000000                             8828.000000
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split the line.  It appears that your delimiter is just whitespace?  You can do something on the order of:

```
@line = split(" ", $line);
```

This will match all whitespace.  You can then do bounds checking and access each field via $line[0], $line[1], etc.

Split can also take a regular expression rather than a string as a delimiter as well.

```
@line = split(/\s+/, $line);
```

This might do the same thing.

Comment: I think he is talking about fixed width encoding.

Comment: Used this method - works great, output:
Time: 1253592000
Livereporter: 
Span: 
Bcreporter: 
Time: 1253678400
Livereporter: 86400
Span: 6183.000000
Bcreporter: 
Time: 1253764800
Livereporter: 86400
Span: 4486.000000
Bcreporter: 
Time: 1253851200
Livereporter: 36.000000
Span: 86400
Bcreporter: 10669.000000
Time: 1253937600
Livereporter: 0.000000
Span: 86400
Bcreporter: 9126.000000
Time: 1254024000
Livereporter: 0.000000
Span: 86400
Bcreporter: 2930.000000
Time: 1254110400
Livereporter: 0.000000
Span: 86400
Bcreporter: 2895.000000
Time: 1254196800
Livereporter: 0.000000
Span: 8828.000000

Comment: You can't split on whitespace because some fields are empty. You lose the column order when you do this.

Comment: I'm going to test out the unpack solution in a few minutes. - Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If all fields have the **same** fixed width and are formatted with spaces, you can use the following `split`:

```
@array = split / {1,N}/, $line;
```

where `N` is the with of the field.  This will yield a space for each empty field.

Comment: I don't think that does what you think it does. There are two major errors in that one line: one in logic and one in syntax.

Comment: @brian d foy: thank you, fixed.  Sorry for a low-quality answer.  Anyway, `unpack` solution is way better.

Answer (score -2):

Fixed width delimiting can be done like this:

```
my @cols;
my %header;
$header{field1} = 0; // char position of first char in field
$header{field2} = 12;
$header{field3} = 15;

while(<IN>) {

   print chomp(substr $_, $header{field2}, $header{field3}); // value of field2 


}
```

My Perl is very rusty so I am sure there are syntax errors there. but that is the gist of it.

Comment: Why are you chomping like that? And what do you think that prints? See the documentation for chomp for a clue. Not to be too mean about it, but if you're guessing and showing something you've never tried or even run, you should wait for a more experienced person to answer.