# Cutting apart string in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a string in Perl that is 23 digits long.  I need to cut it apart into different pieces.  First 2 digits in one variable, next 3 in another variable, next 4 into another variable, etc.  Basically the 23 digits needs to end up as 6 separate variables (2,3,4,4,3,7) characters, in that order.

Any ideas how I can cut the string up like this?

Comment: Duplicate of several questions: [In Perl, how can I unpack to several variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165099/), [Can I use Perl's unpack to break up a string into vars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534455/), [Read chunks of data in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144445/)

Comment: [How do I read fixed length records in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407407/), [How can I break apart fixed-width columns in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893830/), [parse fixed width files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911044/), [How can I extract columns from a fixed-width format in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494611/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do it, but the shortest is probably [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html):

```
my $string = '1' x 23;
my @values = unpack 'A2A3A4A4A3A7', $string;
```

If you need separate variables, you can use a list assignment:

```
my ($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4, $v5, $v6) = unpack 'A2A3A4A4A3A7', $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Alex's method, rather than specify each start and end, use the list you gave of lengths.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw";
my $pos = 0;
my @split = map { 
  my $start = $pos; 
  my $end = $_;
  $pos += $end;
  substr( $string, $start, $end);
} (2,3,4,4,3,7);

print "$_\n" for @split;
```

This said you probably should look at [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) which is used for fixed width fields. I have no experience with it though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex, viz:

```
$string =~ /\d{2}\d{3}\d{4}\d{4}\d{3}\d{7}/
```

and capture each part by surrounding with brackets ().

You then find each capture in the variables $1, $2 ...
or get them all in the returned list

See [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [perldoc substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html).

```
$substring = substr($string, $start, $length);
```

I'd also use `map' on a list of [start, length] pairs to make your life easier:

```
$string = "123456789";
@values = map {substr($string, $_->[0], $_->[1])} ([1, 3], [4, 2] , ...);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a sub that will do it, using the already discussed `unpack`.

```
sub string_slices { 
    my $str = shift;
    return unpack( join( 'A', '', @_ ), $str );
}
```